# How to prevent ImageView of being transparent when using a transparent Bitmap

Tags: java, android, user-interface, background, transparency

May be it's not worth to ask such a silly question. So i apologize at beginning.
What i want to do is I've a transparent bitmap to be displayed with ImageView.
I don't want user to see what is prompted in the background of ImageView.
Now how could i prevent ImageView from being transparent?

If i set ImageView-backgroundColor then it'll be showing that color in background & bitmap might not be displayed properly.

Can anybody help me out of this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use back ground color white. The image would remain transparent. There's an app which uses such method. Difference is they use theme color to be displayed as background.

Answer (score 0):

Add ImageView to any layout that can have background color set - like FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background of the ImageView to #00000000 which will set the background of ImageView to transparent.